# Initializing union type in typescript

Tags: typescript

This gives an error in the asd and sdf functions that the variable o's type is not compatible with the initialization:

```
enum E {
    a,b,c,d
}

type Xe = E.a | E.b;
type Ye = E.c | E.d;

interface X {
    f: Xe;
}

interface Y {
    f: Ye;
}

type I = X | Y;

function asd(v: E) {
    // Error
    const o: I = {
        f: v,
    };
}

function sdf(o: I) {
    if (o.f == E.a) {
        // type of o should be narrowed down to X
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Type '{ f: E; }' is not assignable to type 'I'.
  Type '{ f: E; }' is not assignable to type 'Y'.
    Types of property 'f' are incompatible.
      Type 'E' is not assignable to type 'Ye'.
```

For some reason, type I is not equivalent to this interface:

```
interface I {
    f: Xe | Ye;
}
```

I would like to be able to both initialize and narrow the type in conditions. But  if I don't use union types, narrowing types doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: No, union doesn't merge inner field types, so `I` is equivalent to `{ f: Xe } | { f: Ye }`

Comment: maybe it's impossible what I want to achive if it doesn't merge inner fields, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add an Merge type which creates union types for inner fields:

```
type Merge<This, Other> = {
    [T in Extract<keyof This, keyof Other>]: This[T] | Other[T];
}
```

This takes all keys which are on both interfaces (`Extract<keyof This, keyof Other>`) and creates an union type for it.

```
type I = Merge<X, Y>;
```

would be equivalent to:

```
type I = {
    f: Xe | Ye;
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a little more clear.
My problem with this solution is that type narrowing doesn't seem to work.